# Check if integer is a palindrome in base 10

Tags: c

Here is the solution->

```
//Write a program to check the number whether it is palindrome or not
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void){

//Put variables for the further proceed
int number, quotient=1, remainder,i=0;

//To declare a character array
char text[100];

//To show the message to the user
printf("Enter an integer number :");

//Taking input from the user
scanf("%d",&number);

//For finding escape the integer number in the reverse order specifically
int number_update=number;

//To find out the integer number in the reverse order
  while(quotient!=0){
  quotient=number_update/10;
  remainder=number_update%10;
  number_update=quotient;
  text[i] = remainder + '0';//Converts integer to character and store to the array
  i++;
  }
 //Converts the string to a whole integer
  int result_of_reverse=atoi(text);

  //Check the result of reverse order with the given integer number
  if(result_of_reverse==number){

    //To display the result
    printf("This is a palindrome number");
  }
  else{

    //To display the result
    printf("This is not a palindrome number");
  }

  }
```

I want to achieve: How can I simplify my solution? Is there any better strategy should I follow to solve these types of problems?

Comment: Every integer is a palindrome in some base. I have updated the title to be specific that you are looking for base 10 palindromes....

Comment: Is converting to string allowed? If so, [`snprintf`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snprintf-c-library/) and char-wise compare would seem 'simpler'. Not necessarily faster or a better idea, just simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Too many comments, and they do not serve any purpose.
- Use all necessary `#include`s. `atoi` requires `#include <stdlib.h>`.
- Separate IO from the business logic. Constructing the reversed number definitely belongs to a function.
- There is no need to convert the number into a textual representation. Consider building the reversed number as you compute the digits of the original:

  ```
  int reverse (int number) 
  {
      int reversed = 0;
      while (number != 0) {
          int last_digit = number % 10;
          number /= 10;
          reversed *= 10;
          reversed += last_digit;
      }
      return reversed;
  }
  ```

  As a side effect, many variables (`quotient`, `remainder`, `number_update`, `i`) disappear.

Comment: I got it, sir. Your logic helps me a lot. Thank you.@vnp

Comment: `reversed *= 10;` prone to overflow and undefined behavior.  Try `reverse (1000000009)`.  As is, code is broke for many `int` values.

Answer (score 4):

there is no need to input the 'number' as a `int`.

suggest:

```
char array[30]
char reversed[30] = {0}
scanf( "%29s", array ) to input the number 
size_t len = strlen( array ) to obtain the length of the array,
for( size_t i=0; i < len/2; i++ ) {...} to reverse the array,
strcmp( array, reversed ) to make the comparison
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can I simplify my solution? Is there any better strategy should I follow to solve these types of problems?

When using an `int` only solution, a common problem occurs with values like 1000000009, that when reversed, 9000000001, exceed the `int` range.

To solve the range issue, only form the reverse of the first half of the digits and compare that to the remainder.  No need to form the entire reversed value, just half of it.

```
// valid for i >= 0
bool palindrome_test(int i) {
  int nines = 9;
  int reversed = 0;
  while (i > nines) {
    nines = nines * 10 + 9;
    reversed = reversed * 10 + i % 10;
    i /= 10;
  }
  if (nines/10 < i) {  // odd number of i digits, we do not care about the middle digit.
    return i/10 == reversed;
  }
  return i == reversed;
}
```

Tested correct for all `i >= 0`.

Employing [@Deduplicator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249618/check-if-integer-is-a-palindrome-in-base-10/249970?noredirect=1#comment490328_249970) good idea:

```
bool palindrome_test(int i) {
  int power_of_ten = 10;
  int reversed = 0;
  while (i >= power_of_ten) {
    power_of_ten *= 10;
    reversed = reversed * 10 + i % 10;
    i /= 10;
  }
  if (power_of_ten <= i * 10) {
    return i / 10 == reversed;
  }
  return i == reversed;
}
```

Comment: You know, if you use a power of ten instead of one less, and change < / > to <= / >=, you save an addition.

Comment: @Deduplicator Good optimization idea.